# Accesing to JSON nested values (arrays) from Django templates

Tags: python, arrays, json, django

I have the following `JSON` document with the next structure:

```
{
  "paciente": {
    "id": 1234,
    "nombre": "Pablo Andrés Agudelo Marenco",
    "sesion": {
      "id": 12345,
      "juego": [
        {
          "nombre": "bonzo",
          "nivel": [
            {
              "id": 1234,
              "nombre": "caida libre",
              "segmento": [
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Hombro",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "Flexion",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 12345,
                      "nombre": "Extensión",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Escápula",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "Protracción",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 12345,
                      "nombre": "Retracción",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "___léeme___": "El array 'iteraciones' contiene las vitorias o derrotas con el tiempo en segundos de cada iteración",
              "iteraciones": [
                {
                  "victoria": true,
                  "tiempo": 120
                },
                {
                  "victoria": false,
                  "tiempo": 232
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Some times, the `segmento` array

```
"paciente": ...
   "sesion": ...
       "juego": ...
           **"segmento":[{"id": ...,"nombre":...},{"id": ...,"nombre":...},{"id": ...,"nombre":...}]**
```

came with more that one value, two, three and until four values, all inclusive or not.

I should show these `segmento.nombre`  values in a Django template of the following way:

Each `segmento.nombre` value I should show it in one tab `html div` in my template so for example:

If in my `JSON` document I read only two values into `segmento` array ...

```
{
  "segmento": [{
    "id": 12345,
    "nombre": "Escapula",
  }, {
    "id": 12345,
    "nombre": "Hombro",
  }]
}
```

Then, I should show these two values in my template as :

[image]

**I am read the JSON document**

```
<code> ...
with open('ProcessedMetrics.json') as data_file:
            session_data=json.loads(data_file.read())
            context['session_data'] = session_data
<code> ...
```

**And in my template, I am doing the following:**

```
<!-- jugar con los ciclos del segmento, movimiento -->
<div class="box-body">

  <!-- begin corporal segments tabs -->
  <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
        {% for nest2 in nest1.items %} <!-- get all games (juego array)-->
            {%for nest3 in nest2%}
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">                                  
                        <a href="#mano" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square">{{nest3}}</i> 
                                            </a></li>   

            {%endfor%}    
        {%endfor%}    
    {%endfor%}    
                    <li><a href="#codo" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> other tab hardcoded</a></li>
                </ul>
```

The result which I get until the moment is:

[image]

I am getting problems to forward the `nivel` or `segmento` array ...
I don't know how to access to nested elements in a optime way

Somebody can orient me, the idea is to generate tabs according to the number of values of `segment` array

I appreciate highly your support

Comment: You should really do the processing of the immense JSON structure in Python, and keep the code in the template as simple as possible.

Comment: In that sense, is possible that turn the JSON to dictionary and send it to template may be one alternative?

Comment: you already do that (json.loads turns the JSON into a dictionary). I would make a Python function that takes that dictionary and returns the exact format that would be easiest to use in your template, and call that function from the view.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was shared with me in other forum, and I added the tab and it works in relation with the `segment` values in JSON.

The key is in the tab `href` identifier in the `ul` and `div` where I created the tab and the correlation with the `div id` in where the content of these tab was deployed.

in this way also I know if this is the best option.

```
<div class="box-body">
    <!-- begin corporal segments tabs -->
        <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
                    {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %} 
                        {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento%}
                            <li><a href="#{{nest3.nombre}}" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> {{nest3.nombre}}</a></li>
                        {%endfor%}
                    {%endfor%}
                {%endfor%}    
            </ul>
<!--- Content of tabs generated above -->                                   
<div class="tab-content">
    {% for nest1 in session_data.paciente.sesion.juego %}
        {% for nest2 in nest1.nivel %}
            {%for nest3 in nest2.segmento%}

            <!-- /.tab-pane  Correlation with href tab above-->

                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{nest3.nombre}}">
                <!-- The timeline -->
                    <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                       .... More code ....
                    </div>
               </div>
        ......
 </div>
```

Doing that I can generate a specific tab number according to the number of values in my `segmento` key in the JSON read, and associate it with these tabs to their respective content ...

If somebody have a better option for doing this, please comment!!
For instance it will be better do not perform many loops in my template, this is processing in beside client, really?

Can I read the json in my views, turn in dictionary, make some process with their data and send them to my template?

Thanks